# Replace all elements with specific tag with a component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Is it possible ?

Basically what i would like to do is on a event like clicking an 'edit' button i need to replace all elements with a specific tag with an input field i know how to do it with jQuery but would prefer doing it with react.

jQuery/Pseudo Code:

```
$('a').each(function(e,i){
   e.html('<input placeholder="'+ e.text() +'" />');
});
```

Comment: Quick answer is yes, of course this is possible with many designs using React.  One idea would be to make a Component that would have 2 states and a prop that controls the state (editable or link).  When rendering you could then decide which state is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, however react will replace whole element that you render to.

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  const link = links[i];
  ReactDom.render(
    <LinkNode text={link.textContent} />,
    link
  );

  link.style.border = "5px solid red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to replace the anchor tag with an input tag, then the cleaner way would be to use a wrapper and replace the html inside each wrapper with the html for the input field. The wrapper for each element can be assigned by the following using JQuery:

```
$('#notify-container').parent()
```